# Weirdness with beforeRouteLeave, vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm hoping someone can give me some ideas as to what might be happening with my navigation menu on one particular route using vue-router. It's not possible to create a jFiddle to reproduce this, so I'm hoping a description will suffice.

I have a standard vue-cli generated setup, with a router.js and a navigation menu in my App.vue file, and it all works fine, most of the time. Having navigated to one particular route, though, the menu becomes completely unresponsive - i.e., selecting another menu item does nothing, it doesn't take me to a different route.

The only thing I could think of which might explain this would be the 'beforeRouteLeave' navigation guard I have in place, for example if 'next' wasn't being called. And in fact once I put in some logging, it showed behaviour which for me is completely inexplicable. Here's my 'beforeRouteLeave' for the component in question:

```
    beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
      console.log("Running beforeRouteLeave");
      if (this.editMode && this.isDirty(this.sale)) {
        console.log("beforeRouteLeave: showing leave confirmation");
        bootbox.confirm("Leave without saving?", (result) => {
          if (result) {
            next();
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.log("beforeRouteLeave: going to next()");
        next();
      }
   }
```

When the navigation fails to work, the console shows just the "Running beforeRouteLeave" message. But this is mystifying to me, because I have an if/else test immediately afterwards, both branches of which involve a message being printed to the console. It surely MUST print either "beforeRouteLeave: showing leave confirmation", or "beforeRouteLeave: going to next()". But it prints neither, and the route remains unchanged (so has effectively been aborted, I assume). What could be going on?

Comment: do you see any error in the console?

Comment: No, no error in the console. Bizarrely, it is as if the code has simply stopped executing after the initial "Running beforeRouteLeave" console message. As I said, I don't see how this is possible, as one branch of the if/else must surely be executed.

Comment: The problem is definitely to do with 'beforeRouteLeave'. I've tried removing the beforeRouteLeave function and everything behaves just as it should. I do need the function in place, though.

Comment: what is `this` in the function, try logging it, maybe it's not the `this` you expect

Comment: `this` is the component. But whatever `this` is, one branch of the if/else **must** be executed, but nothing is appearing in the console and no navigation is occurring - that's the mystery.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I ran an 'npm update' to update all packages (vue, vue-router, etc.) to the latest versions and now everything works as it should. So obviously some bug in an old version. Still mystified about how it could simply not execute some code, but I can move on now.